# deploying asp.net core web app with Visual Studio fails

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, msdeploy

Im trying to deploy an Asp.Net Core web app to my local IIS () using Visual Studio 2015.  It gets to the point of using MSDeploy, then throws some authentication errors.  I don't receive these when trying to deploy a standard asp.net web api or mvc application.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

edit:  here is my .pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
<WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
<LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
<ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
<PublishFramework>netcoreapp1.0</PublishFramework>
<UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
<publishUrl>C:\Users\me\Documents\MyProfilePublish</publishUrl>
<DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What does your pubxml file look like?

Comment: @chief7 added it to the post.

Comment: Does the user your running as have Admin acccess to the box?  Have you tried running VS as Admin?  Are you tied to the FileSystem publish method?  If not, try MSDeploy.

Comment: I messed up and posted the wrong .pubxml.  The one that fails is publishing to IIS.  Publishing to the file system works fine.  Both IIS and VS are on the same machine and VS is ran as Admin.  I'm getting too frustrated with it, giving up, and sticking with publishing to the filesystem.

Comment: Could you push the full build Output? Remember to set the verbosity to Detail: Tools=>Option=>Projects And Solutions => Build and Run